# Finding a list of all possible children for an XML element via XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I have XML that includes elements that have optional child elements.  So, the input XML might look like:

```
<parent>
   <element1>data</element1>
   <element2>data</element2>
</parent>
<parent>
   <element1>data</element1>
   <element3>data</element3>
</parent>
<parent>
   <element2>data</element2>
   <element3>data</element3>   
</parent>
<parent>
   <element3>data</element3>
   <element4>data</element4>   
</parent>
```

My goal is to use this input XML to create a list of all child elements under all of the `<parent>` elements.

So, for the XML snippet above, the corresponding output would be:

```
element1
element2
element3
element4
```

At this point, I do not care about the data contained within these child elements.

How might this be accomplished with XSLT?

FWIW, I'm using Saxon-HE 10.5J from Saxonica for the XSLT transform.

Comment: I believe the solution is trivial using [distinct-values](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-distinct-values).

Comment: P.S. The input XML can **NOT** look like that; it must have a single root element.

Comment: I'm guessing your real input has a root node? Something simple like this would do the trick : distinct-values(//parent/*/name())

Comment: The XML would have a root node...that was just a snippet for an example.  I will try the distinct-values...thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With this (viable, including a root element and namespace) XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A:root xmlns:A="http://mailbox.zork.net/A/1.9/">
  <A:parent>
    <A:element1>data</A:element1>
    <A:element2>data</A:element2>
  </A:parent>
  <A:parent>
    <A:element1>data</A:element1>
    <A:element3>data</A:element3>
  </A:parent>
  <A:parent>
    <A:element2>data</A:element2>
    <A:element3>data</A:element3>
  </A:parent>
  <A:parent>
    <A:element3>data</A:element3>
    <A:element4>data</A:element4>
  </A:parent>
</A:root>
```

...and this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:A="http://mailbox.zork.net/A/1.9/"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://mailbox.zork.net/A/1.9/"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|text()"/>
  <xsl:template match="/A:root">
    <xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(./A:parent[*]/*/name())"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the following output:

```
A:element1 A:element2 A:element3 A:element4
```

...which is pretty much exactly what I wanted.

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Could be much shorter: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93F8dVa